# Решение олимпиадной задачи подсуммы

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Вообщем есть последовательность чисел

```
A_1,A_2,...A_N. (-10^9 <= A_i <= 10^9, N < 10^5)
```

нам нужно найти в этой последовательности количество подотрезков, модуль суммы на которых больше чем M.

Comment: На сколько большим может быть N? Решение за O(N^2) вас устроит?

Comment: да простите, что не указал ограничения для N. N <= 10^5. Поэтому N^2 не зайдет(

Comment: неясно что называется подотрезком и что такое сумма этого подотрезка ?

Comment: @ampawd пусть `1 <= L <= R <= N`, тогда `A_L, ..., A_R` - подотрезок, а `A_L + ... + A_R` - сумма этого подотрезка.

Answer (score 3):

Решение за `O(N log N)`.

Сразу пишу в псевдокоде. Операции на дереве работают за логарифм от его размера.

1. сделать суммы от 0 до текущего
2. загнать их в дерево
3. пройтись по этим суммам и используя дерево вычислить сколько из них меньше текущая минус M
4. вывести ответ

Вместо дерева (написанного руками) можно использовать например tree из G++

Чуть изменить чтобы хранить несколько одинаковых значений (например сведением к паре).

```
int main(){
int N, M;
cin >> N >> M;
vector<int> a;
a.push_back(0);
for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    a.push_back(x);
}
int p = 0;
int s = 0;
for (auto i : a){
    s+=i;
    H.insert(pii(s,p++));
}
int res = 0;
s = 0;
for (auto i : a){
    s += i;
    auto q = lower_bound(H.begin(), H.end(), pii(s - M,-1));
    res += H.order_of_key(*q);
}
cout << res<<endl;
}
```

Запускаемая ссылка http://ideone.com/WuJMjz

Comment: О каком дереве идет речь? `set` реализован как красно-черное дерево. Почему бы его не использовать?

Comment: @pank а вы умеете из set получать порядковый номер элемента? Я лично не умею. Можете рассказать как?

Comment: да проблема. А вы учитываете, что значения в массиве могут быть отрицательными?

Comment: @pank сделал запускаемый пример, чтобы может понятнее было.

Comment: `pii` что за зверь?

Comment: @pank pair<int,int> альяс

Comment: не получается запустить :) http://ideone.com/6ohzX9

Comment: @pank дык в дереве то не int лежит а pii http://ideone.com/WuJMjz

Comment: не работает для `a={1, -2, 3}; M=0`. Ответ должен быть 4, а выводит 6: http://ideone.com/gDBngf

Comment: @pank ну вы с 0 аккуратнее) и ответ 5 кстати нормальный.

Comment: для этого шесть: {1}, {-2}, {3}, {1, -2}, {-2, 3}, {1, -2, 3}

Comment: `a={2, -2} M=1`

Comment: @pank а вы сколько хотели? 2 - правильный ответ в этом случае...

Comment: Да тут 2 правильный ответ. Проверил еще на нескольких примерах - вроде работает правильно. Осталось понять как)

Answer (score 2):

Навскидку - собрать все частичные суммы

```
a1  a1+a2  a1+a2+a3 ...
```

потом пробежаться по всем парам `(i,j)` массива частичных сумм - `abs(S(j)-S(i))` будет соответствующей суммой подотрезка. Выбрать подходящие.

Частичная сумма есть в стандартной библиотеке :)

Comment: простите но это за N^2.

Comment: А вы разве указали требуемую скорость в условии?